# AWS codedeploy deployment throwing "no such file or directory" error on Install step

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Following is the error displayed on console -

```
No such file or directory - /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/c71b93a2-8561-41e2-b90f-d638548e7b4c/d-ZR3LMIIZG/deployment-archive/codebase/app/webroot/openx/lib/ad_agencies/admarvel_rtb.php
```

This is the first of the group of files mentioned in the source-destination pairs in appspec.yml

Following is the error log trail (from /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log)-

```
2016-07-27 12:29:00 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(9507)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/c71b93a2-8561-41e2-b90f-d638548e7b4c/d-ZR3LMIIZG/deployment-archive/codebase/app/webroot/openx/lib/ad_agencies/admarvel_rtb.php - /usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1380:in `initialize'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1380:in `open'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1380:in `copy_file'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:394:in `block in cp'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1558:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1574:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:1556:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/share/ruby/2.0/fileutils.rb:393:in `cp'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/install_instruction.rb:236:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/installer.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in install'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/installer.rb:42:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/installer.rb:42:in `block in install'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/installer.rb:41:in `open'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/installer.rb:41:in `install'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:114:in `block in <class:CommandExecutor>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:62:in `execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:132:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in `perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:38:in `block in run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:37:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:70:in `block in run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:69:in `run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:33:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:202:in `block in spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in `spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:192:in `block in spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in `times'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in `spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:134:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:37:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:37:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:262:in `block in call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:84:in `<main>'
```

The current deployment ID is d-ZR3LMIIZG.

I am trying to understand the meaning of this error, and what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Did you confirm the presence of file at that path?

Comment: I guess this was due to a silly mistake - missed selecting the folder codebase while creating the zip, because later when I created the zip, it was correctly getting created. My bad